# Clean column values using string matching

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I have a pandas column with thousand of company name values, a name can have many variations, but it ultimately refers to the same company name. I was thinking of doing some string matching using fuzzywuzzy that ultimately scans each value and replaces it with the value with the least length of characters that is a match, but I don't know how to put it into code.

An example of the output I am hoping for is below

```
company = ['Canopy Growth', 'Canopy Growth Chocolates', 'Canopy growTH', 'Aurora', 'Aurora Drift', 'Aurora Corp', 'Hexo Corp', 'HEXO', 'hexo Inc', 'Pure Sunfarms', 'Pure sunfarms Corp']

clean_company = ['Canopy Growth', 'Canopy Growth', 'Canopy Growth', 'Aurora', 'Aurora', 'Aurora', 'HEXO', 'HEXO', 'HEXO', 'Pure Sunfarms', 'Pure Sunfarms' ]

# create dataframe with company names
df = pd.DataFrame({'company': company, 'clean_company': clean_company})

df
```

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: how is the original data?

Comment: Would you pre-define  the `clean-company` names or how are you trying to achieve this?

Comment: create a search space with all the names... pop the first off and check every other name for similarity using fuzzywuzzy ... any that are simillar enough (above some threshold) you can group with this term and remove from the search space ... repeat until search space is empty ... I dont think you can do it vectorized or anything cool ... it might take a while (depending on how big your search space is)

Comment: @biyazelnut, pretty much like the image, but with thousands of rows.

Comment: MarceloPaco, there is no pre-defined clean-company names

Answer (score 0):

create a search space with all the names... pop the first off and check every other name for similarity using fuzzywuzzy ... any that are simillar enough (above some threshold) you can group with this term and remove from the search space ... repeat until search space is empty ... I dont think you can do it vectorized or anything cool ... it might take a while (depending on how big your search space is) ... something like the following i think

```
def close_enough(group,word,threshold=0.9):
    if fuzzy.eval(group[0],word) > threshold:
       group.append(word)
       return True

def search_matches(words):
    groups = []
    while words:
        a_group = [words.pop(0)]
        words = [w for w in words if not close_enough(a_group,w)]
        # append this group sorted so smallest is first
        groups.append(sorted(a_group,key=len))
    # return our similar groups
    return groups
         

search_space = list(set(df['company'].str.lower()))
simillar_groups = search_matches(search_space)
print(simillar_groups)
# [[a,ab,...],[c,cn,..],]
mapper = {g[0]:v for g in simillar_groups for v in g}
df["normalized_names"] = df["company"].str.lower().map(mapper)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not working as expected